# attached .doc is opening properly in pc but in mobile its not opening properly while sending by smtp in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, jquery-mobile, smtp

- im creating .doc file and sending mail. in pc dowloaded file from
  attachment is opening properly but in mobile its not opening
  properly.     only html tags are displaying in smart phones.can u
  tell me how to render this .doc file so that in mobile also attached
  file can be displayed ?
- attached file is not supporting in smartphones .only html tags are
  displaying.
  can anyone tell in my code how to use docX library in my code?

  ```
  protected void btnMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  DisplayProgressBar();

  Response.Clear();

  try
  {
      if (Session["Projectname"] != null && Session["Projectname"].ToString() != string.Empty)
      {
          string Projname = Session["Projectname"].ToString();
          System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
          System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
          design.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
          string strBuilder = stringWrite.ToString();
          string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".doc";
          LblNoteMsg.Text = strPath;
          //code changed to send mails
          if (File.Exists(strPath))
          {
              var counter = 1;
              strPath = strPath.Replace(".doc", " (" + counter + ").doc");
              while (File.Exists(strPath))
              {
                  strPath = strPath.Replace("(" + counter + ").doc", "(" + (counter + 1) + ").doc");
                  counter++;
              }
          }
          using (var fStream = File.Create(strPath))
          {
               fStream.Close();
               fStream.Dispose();
          }
           using(StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(strPath))
             {
          sWriter.Write(strBuilder);
          sWriter.Close();
          sWriter.Dispose();
          Response.Clear();
             }
          DateTime input = DateTime.Now;
          int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek;
          DateTime dats = DateTime.Now.AddDays(delta);
          //this week
          DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);
          string MonDate = monday.ToShortDateString();
          DateTime sat = monday.AddDays(5);
          string SatDate = sat.ToShortDateString();
          StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/WeeklyMail.txt"));
          string body = r.ReadToEnd();
          MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
          string MailId = txtMailId.Text;
          foreach (string ss in MailId.Split(",".ToCharArray()))
          {
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ss) == false)
              {
                  Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ss));
              }
          }
          Msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("support@sunlightit.com"));
          body = body.Replace("<%MonDate%>", MonDate);
          body = body.Replace("<%SatDate%>", SatDate);
          Msg.Subject = "Weekly status Report of " + Projname + "," + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "";
          Msg.Body = body;
          Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
          Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(strPath));
          SmtpClient MailServer = new SmtpClient();
          try
          {
              MailServer.Send(Msg);
              string reply = (Msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess).ToString();
              if (reply == "OnSuccess")
              {
                  txtMailId.Text = "";
                  tblMail.Visible = false;
                  lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                  lblMsg.Text = "Mail has send succesfully";
              }
              else
              {
                  lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                  lblMsg.Text = "Mail delivery unsuccessfull";
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(ex);

              if (ex.InnerException != null)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("InnerException is: {0}", ex.InnerException);
              }
          }

      }
      else
      {
          Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
      }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('It is being used by another process.Please Try after sometime ');", true);
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You did not make a proper `.doc` file. A `.doc` file is not composed of HTML. Word on your computer does know HTML so it will open the file, but likely the program you're using on the mobile devices will just treat it as a corrupted `.doc` file.

Instead, you should build a proper Word document. There's plenty of libraries for generating `.docx` Open Office XML Document (Word 2007) files. Find one that works for you needs, and use it.

Comment: @rahulkumar No, I didn't say anything about changing your markup. I said you should use a proper library capable of generating actual `.docx` files instead of fake `.doc` files.

Comment: can u tell me one library by which i can generate mobile supported .doc files?

Comment: @rahulkumar I do not know of any libraries for generating `.doc` files. That format is proprietary, old, and uncommon now, and you should switch to `.docx`. There's the [Open Office XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) and [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/). DocX is probably easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Write the file on the server path and pass the link to user make the download:

Example:
http://yourapp.com/files/download/051651203210.doc